# program for an database connection in java

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am facing problem how want to connect the `MySQL` database through `JDBC` (please provide some tips or tutorials link) and how to retrieve the table rows in the output console .

Another thing is that I want some tips or tutorials regarding how to `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE & SELECT` & search in the database through `JDBC`?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Have you tried something that didn't work? Are you looking for tutorials or tips? Some more info would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is short example which does the things you require:
[DevDaily.com - A Simple JDBC Example](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/JDBC-SQLProcessor/Simple_JDBC_Example.shtml).